# Spring RestTemplate авторизация через куки

Tags: java, spring, cookie, аутентификация, resttemplate

На сервере авторизация через куки. Данные принимает как форму. Первый запрос проходит нормально, второй выдает ошибку. Как с RestTemplate отправлять подобные запросы, чтобы сохранялась авторизация?

```
RestTemplate client = new RestTemplate();
headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE));
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("user", login);
map.add("pass", password);
entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
HttpEntity<String> response = client.exchange(server, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("action", "post_sms");
map.add("message", code);
map.add("target", userData.getPhone());
entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
response = client.exchange(server, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить заголовок `Set-Cookie` из первого ответа и добавить заголовок `Cookie` для последующих запросов:

```
...
HttpEntity<String> response = 
        client.exchange(server, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
Optional.ofNullable(response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE)).stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(HttpCookie::parse)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(HttpCookie::toString)
        .forEach(c -> headers.add(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, c));
...
```